# Access Android mobile from PC over the Internet

Tags: c#, android

Remote access from PC to mobile over the internet not using wifi, bluetooth or usb cable, I need to implement like teamviewer quick support connect system to mobile then access mobile.

Comment: you can use teamviewer API and develop your own app.

https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=teamviewer+api&oq=teamviewer+api&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j69i59.2191j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: i dont need third part api